# How can I block images using js only?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to block all the images of any web page to lower the page loading time, consider the web page source code is loaded into browser but the documents/files still needed to be downloaded, is there any event to cover this problem?

I think can method must be followed in browsers text only mode.

Comment: Please describe the exact issue. Refer- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am not sure if this is a developer question or not. Are you building some external plugins?

Comment: Actually i have some work regarding the imacro script to acees the whole website, so i need to load webpages as fast as they can, so for this i can build a plugin which block all the images of any webpages

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it solves your problem but maybe you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() { $("img").removeAttr("src"); } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If the src tag is already set the browser will Load the images no matter what. Remove the src tag after it was loaded doesn't change the fact that it was already downloaded.

The only way to avoid this is to set the src tags of imgs by Javascript dynamicly. And therefore not set images if you don't want to.

You can't make the browser not loading images if it's already in the html.

Comment: Yes, but what you can do is to implement this logic on a server side to avoid image loading in needed cases

Comment: Then how browsers implement "text only" mode, even i have seen some extensions that block the loading of images

Comment: @SahilGoyal a browser isn't the same thing a some javascript file. The browser receives the informations about the pages and decides who can go through and who can't. What you need is go to a browser level and write a plugin. It can't be done from a webpage.

Comment: @SahilGoyal You should ask another quesion properly and say it's for a browser plugin then. Specify browser aswell. right there it sounds like you want to do it from a page access not from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="image"><img external-src="original.jpg" src="fake.jpg" /></div>

$(window).load(function(){
  $('.image img').attr("src", $(this).attr('external-src')).removeAttr('external-src');
});
```

This will load all the images after whole dom loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the whole img tag

```
$("img").remove();
```

or you can just remove the image tag source attribute

```
$("img").removeAttr("src");
```

or you can just replace all the image source having shorter loading time

```
$("img").attr("src",'http://someimage.jpg');
```

Comment: But what about the event, this code is of no use unless i attach with the proper event, i wanna know about that event

Comment: These 3 options were given because by applying first 2 can result in design issue whereas 3rd option can prevent that from happening. So, its upto you to use the desired one.

Comment: But in that case the browser will first download the images and then remove their src attributes

Comment: How about loading a url using ajax and remove the img tag and then load the page.